# Проблема с FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION

Tags: android, android-studio

Отправляю push уведомления. Приходят как положено. Ниже пример отправил 3 уведомления.
При нажатии НА ЛЮБОЕ уведомление первый раз открывается активити ViPe с данными ПЕРВОГО PUSH уведомления. Хотя должны передаваться разные данные.  Видно из скриншота что id разные. При нажатии на остальные ничего не происходит.
В чем может быть причина?

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            }

            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String idz = data.get("idz");
            String idp = data.get("idp");
            String statusnotif = data.get("statusnotif");
            int notifz = Integer.parseInt(data.get("idz"));
            String pbody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String ptitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); 

            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
              sendNotification(pbody,ptitle ,idz,idp,notifz);

            }
        }
```

.

```
private void sendNotification(String body, String title,String idz,String idp,int notifz) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ViPe.class );
        intent.putExtra("idp", idp); 
        intent.putExtra("idz", idz);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound of notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "z"+idz) 
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setColor(Color.GRAY) 
                .setContentTitle(title+' '+idz+' '+idp)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 1000)
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notifz, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а флаг PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT в с какой-то определенной целью используете и надеетесь на какое-то особое поведение, отличное от того, что указано в документации?